# VBA Pivot Table not adding column to xlRowField and xlCount at the same time

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

So when I manually create a pivot table where I just want to use one column and obtain the count of each unique value I'd add that column to the xlRowField and xlCount using the Excel UI.

With the manual approach I'd get something like this:

```
Values  | Count
-------------------
Value 1 | 20
Value 2 | 19
Value 3 | 5
-------------------
Grand Total | 44
```

This is a very simple process and works flawlessly. However, when I try to play back the exact recording with VBA the behaviour changes. Even after a few VBA modifications to simplify it the behaviour still differs from the manual process.

Instead of adding the column data to both xlRowField and xlCount as I had recorded manually it adds it to xlRowField, removes it, and adds it to xlCount leaving me with a table only displaying the grand total.

```
Count
-------------------
Grand Total | 44
```

I'm sure I'm not the only one running into this issue, but I don't really know how to phrase this question so I can find the solutions here on StackOverflow.

EDIT: While messing around with the code one last time before pasting it here I think I sorted it.

Code after a few edits but still essentially the same as the recorded VBA code was as follows.

```
Dim PT As PivotTable
Set PT = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches _
    .Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Sheet1"R1C1:R1048576C1", Version:=6) _
    .CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="Sheet2!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6)

Dim PF As PivotField

With PT
    Set PF .PivotFields("Values")
    PF.Orientation = xlRowField
    PF.Position = 1

    Set PF = .AddDataField(.Pivotfields("Values"), "Count of Values", xlCount)
    .InGridDropZones = True
    .RowAxislayout xlTabularRow
End With
```

The solution I found was just to reverse the order the fields were added to the pivot table. Add the xLcount field first and then the xlRowField.

Comment: Works best here if you show the code you have which isn't working.

Comment: Will add. One moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out actually after randomly messing around with the VBA code a bit more. Kind of feels like it's more of a workaround, but at least it works.

```
Dim PT As PivotTable
Set PT = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches _
    .Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="Sheet1"R1C1:R1048576C1", Version:=6) _
    .CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="Sheet2!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=6)

Dim PF As PivotField

With PT
    Set PF = .AddDataField(.Pivotfields("Values"), "Count of Values", xlCount)
    .InGridDropZones = True
    .RowAxislayout xlTabularRow

    Set PF .PivotFields("Values")
    PF.Orientation = xlRowField
    PF.Position = 1
End With
```

Flipping the two fields within the 'With' block solved the issue. Don't entirely understand why though.